# CSS on iphone 6 not updating

Tags: ios, css, iphone, responsive

I'm developing a website and I use large css file with over 4k lines to provide all styles across the pages. My problem is, that whenever I update the css file and upload it to server, everything works fine on computer, but my iphone 6 refuses to notice any changes.

I even removed the css file from server and accessed the path to find out the file is really not there - but all styles on website keep being applied acting they need no resource to work. In contrary to this - computer notices change and no styles are present.

Why does it behave so weird?

Comment: this could be your phones browser cache saving the css for faster reload time.

Comment: you could use the phone emulation in chrome instead. inside the developer tools